# Can anyone think of a reason why these two ways of writing the same code is causing problems? (very quick)

Tags: css, margin

I am making a container called "fullWidthContainer" to put all my articles and crap in it. 
It needs to be spaced from the top header and the bottom footer so I have gave it a margin of 40px on top and on bottom.

HTML code:

```
<div id="fullWidthContainer class="cAlign">
...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#fullWidthContainer
{
margin: 40px 0 40px 0;
}


.cAlign { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

This is causing all the contents inside to not be aligned in the center. Everything is jacked and aligned to the left.

If I type the above CSS code in this manner....:

```
div#fullWidthContainer
{
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.cAlign { width: 960px; margin: 0, auto; }
```

then it works fine. Why is this? Doesn't it mean the same thing? I feel like this is something very easy that I missed....

Comment: There are typos in your HTML and CSS. Perhaps you should correct those first.

Comment: Sorry about the typos, i rewrote those in the editor on this website and didn't copy and paste. But there's no typos in the actual code.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the help guys. As the answer below says, I messed up in not noticing the "Rank" or specificity as ID > Class. That and 0 != Auto :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because your margin-left and margin-right are not 0 to begin with. In the first code, you set them to 0px. In the second one, you don't touch them.

Comment: OH I see that makes sense. They're clashing. For some reason I thought the 0 left/right margins were the same as the auto. A slip up.. thanks for the help

Comment: No problem. I always assume that any syntax errors in the code are not present in the actual code you're working on, because your HTML and CSS has a lot of missing tags, quotes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`div#fullWidthContainer` has a higher [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) than `.cAlign`, so it overrides it.

So, in the first example, the `margin: 0 auto` from `.cAlign` is overriden by `margin: 40px 0 40px 0` in `div#fullWidthContainer`.

The second example does not set the left and right margin in `div#fullWidthContainer`, so the `auto` value from `.cAlign` is not overridden.

---

As mentioned, there are a few typos in the code. `margin: 0, auto` should be `margin: 0 auto` (without the comma) and `<div id="fullWidthContainer` should be `<div id="fullWidthContainer"` (with a closing quote for the attribute value).

Answer (score 0):

No, neither of those changes results in CSS that "means the same thing".

In the case of `div#fullWidthContainer`, the first code sample sets `margin-left` and `margin-right` to 0, while the second code sample leaves them unaffected.

In the case of `.cAlign`, the first code sample sets `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to 0 and `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`, while the second code sample contains a syntax error (the comma doesn't belong) and, in theory, shouldn't do anything (although in practice, I can understand a browser parsing `0,` as `0` and letting it slide).

Then, since *both* selectors apply to the div in question, precedence comes into play. `div#fullWidthContainer` is more specific than `.cAlign` because it selects an ID, so in the first case, the `margin-left` and `margin-right` values from `div#fullWidthContainer` override the values from `.cAlign`, so you get margins of 0 instead of `auto`.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Yeah I typed that code out real fast in my browser so the typos are my bad but they're not inside the actual code. But I changed it taking precedence into consideration and it works now. :)